# Yad list columns

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need some help with Yad. This is my code:

```
contact=$(while read line
            do
                firstname=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { print $2 }')
                lastname=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { print $3 }')
                num=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { print $4 }')
                birthday=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { print $5 }')

                if [  $firstname != ""  -a  $lastname != "" ] ; then
                    echo "$firstname$lastname"
                else
                    if [ $firstname != "" ] ; then
                        echo "$firstname,"
                    elif [ $lastname != "" ] ; then
                        echo "$lastname"
                    else
                        echo "$num"
                    fi
                fi

            done < "contactlist.txt" )
idlist=$(while read line
            do
                idnum=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { print $1}')
                echo $idnum
            done < "contactlist.txt" )

sortcontact=$(printf "%s\n" $contact | sort)

selected=$(yad --title="Contacts" --width=200 --height=200 --button="DISPLAY:2" --button="ADD:3" --list --separator=""  --column="List" $sortcontact --column="ID:NUM" $idlist)
```

The output in `$idlist` and `$sortcontact` are all mixed up.

I want that the column ID should only have the `$idlist` while the column list should only have the `$sortcontact`.

Comment: And what is `yad`?

Comment: Yad stands for "Yet another dialog" https://code.google.com/p/yad/

Comment: I'd be happy to help but I've got nothing to test against. Could you set up your code so instead of it parsing files, it's just yad running static data? And on the plus site, if that works, you know where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know yad, but it's apparently a fork of zenity, so you probably need to feed it the items the same way as with zenity; `name1 id1 name2 id2` instead of `name1 name2 id1 id2`.

Something like this should be close to what you want, I think.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
items=()
while IFS='|' read -r idnum firstname lastname num birthday _; do
    if [[ $firstname || $lastname ]]; then
        items+=( "$firstname $lastname" "$idnum" )
    else
        items+=( "$num" "$idnum" )
    fi
done < <(sort -t'|' -k2 contactlist.txt)

selected=$(yad --title=Contacts --width=200 --height=200 \
               --button=DISPLAY:2 --button=ADD:3 --list \
               --separator= --column=List --column=ID:NUM \
               "${items[@]}")
```

Comment: Thank youuu! that worked perfectly! Plus you made the code simpler!!